# ListTile onTap property does not work. What is required for it to be triggered?

Tags: flutter, dart, listtile

I am using ListTile in my application. I have an application like below and onTap feature is not triggered here.

I never understood why. I know it's a bad question, but I can't give details because I can't understand why. If there is anything you want me to add, please let me know in the comments.

```
    Widget _buildList(Populations list) {
  return Builder(builder: (context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () => () {
        print('object');
      },
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text(list.animalNo,
              style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 12,
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              )),
          Text(list.group,
              style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                fontSize: 12,
                color:
                    list.error == true ? Color(0xFFFF0000) : Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

ListView.builder

```
   Flexible(
                        child: ListView.separated(
                          itemCount: populations.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return _buildList(populations[index]);
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 10.0),
                              child: Divider(
                                color: Color(0xFF04A1AB),
                                height: 1,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set onTap function wrong, do like this:

```
onTap:() {
        print('object');
      },
```

Comment: Thank you. It's really sad that it doesn't give any typos.